# Is there any Google OAuth2.0 Scope present which can tell me when the user access his account last time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

I know google provides lot of apis/scopes which we can use to manage google account (similar to this https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest?apix=true). I am looking for an scope which can tell me when did user last accessed his/her account. Accessing account means checking email, playing YouTube video, anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can review the [login api](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/login#login_success), using this API  you can verify the last time of a sucessfull login for a Workspace account.

A sample output were the time of the loggin is visible :

```
{
  "kind": "admin#reports#activities",
  "etag": "\"REDACTED\"",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "admin#reports#activity",
      "id": {
        "time": "2021-05-28T19:30:23.868Z",
        "uniqueQualifier": "REDACTED",
        "applicationName": "login",
        "customerId": REDACTED"
      },
      "etag": "REDACTED"",
      "actor": {
        "email": "user@domain.com",
        "profileId": "11111111111111111111"
      },
```

- Please note that this report will log each time a user logs in with google, however if the user already has an active session and access to a google service this action will not be logged.